# How can i split the string only once using C#

Tags: c#

Example : a - b - c must be split as 
a and b - c, instead of 3 substrings

Comment: Its amazing 1000+ questions tagged "programming" I just had to go find out how many quesitons were tagged "question" and there are some!!  @Jon: FYI, SO is always about programming, non programming questions will very quickly get voted closed.

Comment: ...but only 15 questions are tagged "question" ;)

Answer (score 34):

Specify the maximum number of items that you want:

```
string[] splitted = text.Split(new string[]{" - "}, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I personally would have gone with "splat" for the array variable name... if you gonna make up a word, I say go for the gusto!

Comment: Btw, the 2 in the answer represents the number of substrings to return!

Answer (score 16):

```
string s = "a - b - c";
string[] parts = s.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2);
// note, you'll still need to trim off any whitespace
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"a-b-c".Split( new char[] { '-' }, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use indexOf() to find the first instance of the character you want to split with, then substring() to get the two aspects. For example...

```
int pos = myString.IndexOf('-');
string first = myString.Substring(0, pos);
string second = myString.Substring(pos);
```

This is a rough example - you'll need to play with it if you don't want the separator character in there - but you should get the idea from this.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] splitted = "a - b - c".Split(new char[]{' ', '-'}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "a-b-c";
int splitPos = str.IndexOf('-');
string[] split = { str.Remove(splitPos), str.Substring(splitPos + 1) };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have joined late and many of above answers are matched with my following words:

string has its own

> Split

You can use the same to find the solution of your problem, following is the example as per your issue:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var PrimaryString = "a - b - c";
        var strPrimary  = PrimaryString.Split( new char[] { '-' }, 2 );
        Console.WriteLine("First:{0}, Second:{1}",strPrimary[0],strPrimary[1]);

    }
}
```

---

```
Output:
First:a , Second: b - c
```

Comment: This will give you an array with the following `[a,b,c]` and not `[a,b-c]`. Plus wrong language.

Comment: Thanks @JamieR for quoting it. I corrected my answer.