# Regex to split string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have to split a string into two string in C#.
Any text that appears before the first space as one and anything after the other as one.

For example 415 Wall St

415 as one string and Wall St as another string.

14-15 Broadway St

14-15 as one string and Broadway St as another string.

Is there any Regex in C#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you must `TRY` first before asking!

Answer (score 3):

String has a Split method there, you don't need regular expressions for that. And that question has been asked before [How can i split the string only once using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000831/how-can-i-split-the-string-only-once-using-c-sharp)

So in your case that would look like

```
String[] parts = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
String before = parts[0];
String after = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s="14-15 Broadway St";

Regex r=new Regex(@"(^.*?)\s+(.*?$)");

Match m=r.Match(s);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);//14-15
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);//Broadway St
```