# Splitting a string at one spot using a delimiter c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there anyway to split a string into an array at one spot? The string has two or more of the delimiter.

```
string testString = @"test=key=value";
```

Using '=' as a delimiter. How would I split the string into an array with two indices?

```
string testString = @"test=key=value";
                       // ^ Split Here
```

The array will result in: {"test","key=value"}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000831/how-can-i-split-the-string-only-once-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) this will return the index of the first occurrence of the equals sign. You can then split the string using `SubString`:

```
int index = testString.IndexOf('=');
string first = testString.SubString(0, index).Trim();
string second = testString.SubString(index+1).Trim();
```

The call to `Trim` will remove any white space that might be around the equals sign.

Alternatively you could use this [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes the maximum number of strings you wish to return (in this case 2):

```
var result = string.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);
```

You will still need to `Trim` the results to remove white space.

*[Thanks Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480549/splitting-a-string-at-one-spot-using-a-delimiter-c-sharp/37480658?noredirect=1#comment62458431_37480658)*

Comment: Or use `var keyValuePair = string.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);` this will split only on the first occurrence of equals.